# Solving cross-browser type discrepencies?

Tags: css, cross-browser

My aim is have the text inside this div displaying in the middle of it's container cross-browser.

If I could achieve this it would enable me to use fewer images.

http://jsfiddle.net/tMFaD/

Notice how this example looks different in Chrome/Safari and Firefox. The issue seems obviously related to the type/line-height/similar (the '1' is higher up on firefox).

Can this be easily done?

**UPDATE: This is the small difference that i'm trying to solve:** http://cl.ly/2A2o371c2O2r3q0T0R2E

**UPDATE 2: I have not found a definitive cross-browser solution but some of the answers in this thread should come close enough for most. The solution I used was to use a browser-targeted rule for this element. I could also have used images/sprites.**

Comment: Looks the same in Chrome, Firefox & IE9 for me.

Comment: Why not set a `width` and `height`, and then set `text-align:center` and `line-height` same as your `height`? EDIT, and I can't see any difference in Chrome and FF either.

Comment: Also `display:block;` is not needed as DIV is already a block level element.

Comment: @JanHančič see update, Niklas - also tried this, see update.

Comment: @samb, I think you also should defined font-family. (like: arial serif;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set line-height to match the height of the box and then remove the top and bottom padding. That will align it in the (vertical) middle of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

```
.box {
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: pink;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}​

.box {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Both will produce the same results:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s9Urm/8/

**EDIT:** To get the level or cross browser/cross OS precision you're after I think you're going to have to use separate style rules for some of them or just use images.

Comment: For me (os x), in ff, the type is still 2/3px higher up. Very close though.

Comment: If you have a play around with the numbers that should sort itself out.

Comment: http://cl.ly/2A2o371c2O2r3q0T0R2E Obviously this is quite fussy, but it's important

Comment: Try adjusting line height etc. I'm not on OS X so can't really help any more than this. Sorry.

Comment: Out of interest why is the few pixels between browsers so important?

Comment: The real element i'm using is a piece of design that I want to make reusable, it looks quite obvious even if 2/3 pixels. It's also circular. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fair enough. Without images or different stylesheets I don't think you're going to be able to do this.

Comment: yeah I don't think there is a definitive css cross-browser (let alone cross-OS) solution to make this pixel-perfect. I chose to use browser-specific rules to get round my dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

OTHER suggestion, use `line-height` to control `vertical middle` instead of `padding`:

```
.box {
    display:block;
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: pink;
    float: left;
    line-height:80px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}​
```